# IBeacons with proximity and clickable button

Tags: button, bluetooth, ibeacon

I am trying to find informations about IBeacons, plus bluetooth Dash Buttons and google delivers contradictory results.

Is there a IBeacon's with an button to click. And an interface on the connected device to react on the click event?

I need if possible to have the proximity and click event.

Is this even possible with IBeacons/BLE specifications?

All kind of informations are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IoT buttons like Amazon Dash and Bluetooth LE beacons like iBeacon have fundamental differences:

- **Amazon Dash** connects to the internet over WiFi to make a web service call on button press, and requires configuration with your WiFi network.  Other IoT buttons work similarly, although some connect to the internet via a nearby mobile device using Bluetooth.  **You must write some code and deploy it to a cloud server to do something whenever somebody taps the button.**
- **Bluetooth LE beacons** like iBeacon are transmit only Bluetooth LE devices that do not connect to the internet, but simply sent out a bluetooth packet with a unique identifier.  These devices are much simpler, and rely on another bluetooth-enabled computer within 40 meters to be listening (typically a mobile phone).  **You must write an app on the mobile phone then does something when it detects the beacon transmission is detected.**

Most Bluetooth LE beacons are always transmitting, although it is possible to buy ones that are click-on click-off like the [RadBeacon Dot](https://store.radiusnetworks.com/products/radbeacon-dot).  This could provide similar functionality to a Amazon Dash if a mobile app is running nearby that can forward the detection to a similar cloud sever as used for an Amazon Dash solution.

Comment: Cool, thanks for this helpful answer! The RedBeacon Dot is what i searched for. Just one additional question are there also Bluetooth LE buttons that can send some special data(event,variable what ever) when the button is clicked. But be detectable all the time? Or is this not typical because they always just send their id? I am planning to do an app with it and just wanna make sure which technik i can use. Actually if i need a server to get the information to the user doesnt matter so much but i would like to get the proximity informations if possible.

Comment: I am not aware of an off-the-shelf BLE beacon that transmits a specific field when a button is pressed, although this is certainly *possible* to build one to work that way.  Again, the typical setup is for one to transmit only on button click and not transmit at all otherwise.